# MediaPipe Hands gives typeError: hands.Hands is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, mediapipe

I am trying to build a React widget using Googles MediaPipe Hands library.

I get the following error:

`typeError: hands.Hands is not a constructor`

Here is my code!

```
const LandmarkExtractionComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const videoElement = document.getElementById("input_video") as HTMLVideoElement;
        const canvasElement = document.getElementById("output_canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
        const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

        if (!canvasCtx) {
            return;
        }

        const onResults = (results: mpHands.Results): void => {
            canvasCtx.save();
            canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
            canvasCtx.drawImage(results.image, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
            if (results.multiHandLandmarks) {
                for (const landmarks of results.multiHandLandmarks) {
                    drawingUtils.drawConnectors(canvasCtx, landmarks, mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS, {
                        color: "#00FF00",
                        lineWidth: 5
                    });
                    drawingUtils.drawLandmarks(canvasCtx, landmarks, { color: "#FF0000", lineWidth: 2 });
                }
            }
            canvasCtx.restore();
        };

        const hands = new mpHands.Hands({
            locateFile: (_file: string) => {
                return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/hands/${file}`;
            }
        });
    
        hands.setOptions({
            maxNumHands: 1,
            modelComplexity: 1,
            minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
            minTrackingConfidence: 0.5
        });

        hands.onResults(onResults);

        const camera = new cameraUtils.Camera(videoElement, {
            onFrame: async () => {
                await hands.send({ image: videoElement });
            },
            width: 1280,
            height: 720
        });

        camera.start();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <UserInterfaceComponent />
        </div>
    );
};

export default LandmarkExtractionComponent;
```

This is just the basic example used by MediaPipe!

Hope someone can help...

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to get the Hands from the cdn instead of npm package

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).